# NVIDIA RTX 3070 Laptop not working on Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu

I purged everything and then reinstalled driver 460 from scratch. After that operation it gave me an error at grub. But fixed it with the tool to fix grub on live ubuntu.

Now launching nvidia-smi gives me this error

```
➜ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

but

```
➜ dkms status
nvidia, 460.39, 5.4.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.16, 5.4.0-62-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.16, 5.4.0-65-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Same problem here on 20.10. Did you manage to fix the problem? ASUS TUF A15 (2021)

Comment: No, I tried reinstalling from scratch again but nothing..

Answer (score 0):

I've found this to be the solution. Read the steps carefully, starting with Kernel update.

Here is the original copy from the thread. Copyrights as per the link below.

```
1. Get the latest Kernel. Currently it is 5.10.14
2. Download all files from this URL https://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/gs/ and copy them to
/lib/firmware/amdgpu Make sure they all have the same owner and permissions like the other files in the same folder.
3. sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/scripts/module.lds.S -O /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.2-051002-generic/scripts/module.lds
4. sudo sed -i '$ d' /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.2-051002-generic/scripts/module.lds

Make sure you put the correct kernel version instead of "5.10.2-051002"

1. sudo update-initramfs -u
2. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
3. Reboot and install the NVIDIA driver from “System → Preferences → Hardware → Additional Drivers”
```

Source: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ubuntu-mate-20-04-with-rtx-3070-on-ryzen-5900-black-screen-after-boot/167681/30

**Make sure to copy the amdgpu bin files into the right kernel path, as it changes with time so you will end up with different digits.**

Comment: Please include essential parts here. Link only answers will be removed.